# xml to java translation

Tags: java, android, xml

my xml file is this and I want to set it programmaticaly from a class. So far I have some problems.

My xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_weather9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/weather1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So far this is my java code:

```
final LinearLayout test2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        test2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        test2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        final Button Back = new Button(this);
        Back.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Back.setText("Back");

        test2.addView(Back);

        final LoaderImageView image = new LoaderImageView(this, ImageUrl);
        image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

I do not know how to implement the scaleType attribute for java.

Can anyone help me? I have ansked it 2 days ago in SO but the answers were not acceptable.I have already searched but I cannot find the answer. I have already tried this but it doesn't work:

```
image.ScaleType(FILL)
```

EDIT: My image is an Imageloader that extends Image so the image.ScaleTyoe has to be defined for that method. Can anyone help me?

This Is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Handler.Callback;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

/**
 * Free for anyone to use, just say thanks and share :-)
 * @author Blundell
 *
 */
public class LoaderImageView extends LinearLayout{

    private static final int COMPLETE = 0;
    private static final int FAILED = 1;

    private Context mContext;
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private ProgressBar mSpinner;
    private ImageView mImage;

    /**
     * This is used when creating the view in XML
     * To have an image load in XML use the tag 'image="http://developer.android.com/images/dialog_buttons.png"'
     * Replacing the url with your desired image
     * Once you have instantiated the XML view you can call
     * setImageDrawable(url) to change the image
     * @param context
     * @param attrSet
     */
    public LoaderImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
        final String url = attrSet.getAttributeValue(null, "image");
        if(url != null){
            instantiate(context, url);
        } else {
            instantiate(context, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is used when creating the view programatically
     * Once you have instantiated the view you can call
     * setImageDrawable(url) to change the image
     * @param context the Activity context
     * @param imageUrl the Image URL you wish to load
     */
    public LoaderImageView(final Context context, final String imageUrl) {
        super(context);
        instantiate(context, imageUrl);     
    }

    /**
     *  First time loading of the LoaderImageView
     *  Sets up the LayoutParams of the view, you can change these to
     *  get the required effects you want
     */
    private void instantiate(final Context context, final String imageUrl) {
        mContext = context;

        mImage = new ImageView(mContext);
        mImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //mImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        mSpinner = new ProgressBar(mContext);
        mSpinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);

        addView(mSpinner);
        addView(mImage);

        if(imageUrl != null){
            setImageDrawable(imageUrl);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set's the view's drawable, this uses the internet to retrieve the image
     * don't forget to add the correct permissions to your manifest
     * @param imageUrl the url of the image you wish to load
     */
    public void setImageDrawable(final String imageUrl) {
        mDrawable = null;
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mDrawable = getDrawableFromUrl(imageUrl);
                    imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(COMPLETE);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
                }
            };
        }.start();
    }

    /**
     * Callback that is received once the image has been downloaded
     */
    private final Handler imageLoadedHandler = new Handler(new Callback() {
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case COMPLETE:
                mImage.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
                mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case FAILED:
            default:
                // Could change image here to a 'failed' image
                // otherwise will just keep on spinning
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }       
    });

    /**
     * Pass in an image url to get a drawable object
     * @return a drawable object
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws MalformedURLException
     */
    private static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(final String url) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
    }

}
```

EDIT:SOLVED

Answer (score 2):

[`imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29)

Comment: ok code edited because my image is an imageloader that extends imageview and the method has to be defined in the imageloader.java. Can you helo me on that?